# How To Make Input Type TIME 24-hr Format?

Tags: angular, html, angular6, angular7, timepicker

I have this Angular 7 project using Angular Material. I also used the time type in my input tag (HTML5)

```
<input type="time">
```

but I want it to be 24-hr format (not showing the AM/PM options). I've been searching for solutions but none fits for Angular Material projects.

Comment: What about https://agranom.github.io/ngx-material-timepicker/?

Comment: I will try this but it seems to only have the AM/PM option. Thank you

Comment: They have 24 format example too

Comment: Thank you. I will get back to you incase it didn't work ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the timepicker I'm really looking for is just like the one in HTML5 but without the AM/PM, I used @MoshFeu's suggestion which is the Ngx Material Timepicker

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput class="timepicker" [ngxTimepicker]="pickerTwo" [format]=24 placeholder="End" [(ngModel)]="data.formData.end">
</mat-form-field>


<ngx-material-timepicker 
    #picker
    [enableKeyboardInput]=true>
</ngx-material-timepicker>
```

Popup Timepicker: Time can be editable with a static colon in between (not just selecting numbers in the clock). Also has a validation for 24-hr format and can press up or down keys for increment and decrement.

[image]

For the CSS, you can change colors by using `:host /deep/` in the classes

Example:

```
:host /deep/ .timepicker__header {
    background-color: #FF7043 !important;
}
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker) doesn't show putting the `<input>` inside of a `<mat-form-field>` but I couldn't get it to work until I did.

Comment: You need the input field to trigger this clock

Comment: Right, I had the input, it was the mat-form-field that I was missing, which isn't shown in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input matInput type="time-24" [(ngModel)]="timemodel.start">
```

This solved the problem for me.
This made it possible to enter time in 24-hour format on both Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: I see you’re trying to figure out how to display your markup inline. Use three back ticks (`) on the line before and after your code to display it as a code block. Or indent your markup by four spaces. There are also UI controls to help with this.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `type="time"` shows a time picker with AM/PM. But `type="time-24"` does not give me anything and removes the time picker altogether.