# Force the 24h format for input type of time regardless of the system locale

Tags: javascript, html, angular, input, time

I'm working on a small Angular application, and I'm using the following HTML element for when the user sets the start hours:

```html
<input type="time">
```

I've noticed that this element adopts either the 12-hour or 24-hour format based on the user's system locale. Is there a way to consistently enforce the use of the 24-hour format for this element, regardless of the system locale?

Or alternatively, are there any JavaScript workarounds available?

Comment: You can check this answer for angular:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54979634/11152425

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to consistently enforce the use of the 24-hour format for this element, regardless of the system locale?

No, and (per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)):

> In unsupported browsers, the control degrades gracefully to [`<input type="text">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text)

which is even less strict.

If your UI requirements differ from what is afforded by browsers, then you must implement (or find) a custom input that meets those requirements, including [validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#pattern) of the user input.